# How to get all the values from the child nodes in android 4.0?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I would like to list all the values of the  tag inside in android 4.0 as of now I am able to get only one value I have added the snippet which I am using right now & also the xml below.Please help with the this with snippet or example.Thanks a lot.

```
NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("month");
```

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) 
{

```
Element e = (Element) nodes.item(i);

            stock_list.add(getValue(e, "month"));
}



Here is my xml
```

[image]

Comment: Add `Log.i(e.toString())` inside the loop. What does it output? What does your method `getValue` (which you have not shown to us) do?

Comment: Is there any other way to get all the values of <month> tag.

Comment: Thanks Heinzi your soln works!!! just add it as answer I will up vote it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [nodeValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) of an XML Element is `null` by definition. Thus, you can either

- query the element's children for the `Text` node containing the actual contents, or
- simply use [`e.getTextContent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) to retrieve the text content of the XML element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i was having the same problem and solved it this way..

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> stock_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("month");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Node name = nodes.item(i);
    NodeList month = name.getChildNodes();
    map.put("months", ((Node) month.item(0)).getNodeValue());
    stock_list.add(map);
}
```